# _bstr_t to char*, amazing result

Tags: char, bstr

first:

```
LPCTSTR asdfsdf = (LPCTSTR)(_bstr_t)v;
printf("%s\n", asdfsdf);
```

second:

```
printf("%s\n", (LPCTSTR)(_bstr_t)v);
```

they are the same, but the first condition causes unreadable code

why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`_bstr_t` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6(v=vs.71).aspx) encapsulates a BSTR inside a C++ class. In your first instance:

```
LPCTSTR asdfsdf = (LPCTSTR)(_bstr_t)v;
```

you are creating a `_bstr_t` object, extracting the `LPCTSTR` out of it, but then the temporary `_bstr_t` object gets destructed. Whatever `asdfsdf` pointed to is now deallocated and can no longer be used.

In your second example

```
printf("%s\n", (LPCTSTR)(_bstr_t)v);
```

the temporary `_bstr_t` object is not destructed until *after* the `printf()` is called, so there is no problem using the `LPCTSTR` value.

Comment: thanks, but i still have problem.
the variable 'v' above is declared as this:
_variant_t v = ret->GetCollect((long)1);
as you said, _bstr_t object doesn't exist, but variable 'v' still exist. 
why this can't work?

Comment: It doesn't matter what `v` is. The problem is that the `_bstr_t` temporary object creates a *copy* of the data from `v` when it is constructed, and deallocates that copy when the temporary is destructed.